How do I register an event in libevent that does not require a callback function
I am using the libevent library for network service development. One of the event loops not only handles network I/O events but also polls a message queue. I want to block and wait when this thread is idle (meaning there are no I/O events and the queue is empty).
The only method I can think of is to treat the operation of waiting for the queue to be non-empty as an event, so that I can wait for both the I/O events and the queue simultaneously.
However, the event_new function requires me to pass a callback function, and I don't need the callback function to do anything; I just want the thread to resume operation after waiting for an event to occur.
I reviewed the libevent documentation, but I couldn't find any API that could solve my problem.
What I should do? Or is this logic not in line with libevent's development guidelines?

The wrong question
This is the wrong question:

How do I register an event in libevent that does not require a callback function

Of course your event requires a callback function, because every libevent event does.  That's how libevent notifies the application that an event has occurred, so that the application can (optionally) do something about it.
At bare minimum, you might revise that to "an event that does not require its callback to do anything".  That already gives you a potential direction, as a callback that doesn't do anything is trivially easy to write.  But is that really what you need?
No, of course not.  You do want your program to take action: either to block or to unblock (it's not clear to me which).
The wrong model
You say you want to

treat the operation of waiting for the queue to be non-empty as an event

, but that's nonsense.  An operation is not an event.  It might be something done when an event occurs, but the event is "something happens".  New data arrives.  A file descriptor becomes ready.  An adversary appears.  In your case, you could conceivably treat the queue emptying as an event, but waiting for that is a behavior, not an event.
However, waiting is not something you want your callbacks to do, as it will prevent the event loop from dispatching any more events until the wait ends.  Avoiding the need for such waits is one of the objectives of libevent in the first place.
A solved problem
You say:

One of the event loops not only handles network I/O events but also polls a message queue. I want to block and wait when this thread is idle (meaning there are no I/O events and the queue is empty).

This being libevent, I take your "event loop" to be a thread that calls event_base_dispatch() or maybe event_base_loop().  I suppose that the problem you're trying to solve is that the event dispatch function returns when there are no pending or active events, because if it instead just waited for additional events to arrive then that would solve the problem (right?).
But surely you don't think that's an unusual requirement.  It's not, and libevent has it covered.  This is what the EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY flag is for.  You would use it by creating an event_config object, setting the flag on it, and using it to configure the appropriate event base.  Something like this:
    struct event_config *config = event_config_new();
    event_config_set_flag(config, EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY);

    struct event_base *events = event_base_new_with_config(config);

That's just an example.  You must already be doing something related, and you'll need to determine the appropriate way to integrate the additional dispatch-loop flag into your code.
Having done that, your call to the dispatch loop function will just keep waiting for events when there aren't presently any being handled or awaiting dispatch.

Thank you! You're right, I'm looking for a similar function to meet my needs, and I'm not sure if this falls under the category of 'events.'

I would like to add a point because I think you may not fully understand my question (perhaps?). I use event_base_loop(events, EVLOOP_ONCE | EVLOOP_NONBLOCK) in my loop, so after handling an I/O event once, I can also process messages in the queue. This is why I need to block and wait for both the I/O events and for the queue to transition from empty to non-empty; We don't want the CPU to keep running when it's idle.right? So when I determine that the thread is idle, I call event_base_loop(events, EVLOOP_ONCE) until the thread has something to do, and then it enters the next loop...

You're right, @RuiXinLin, it was unclear to me that you were using EVLOOP_ONCE. But that seems counterproductive.  It seems to me that you should trigger message queue processing by firing events, not by dropping out of the event dispatcher to do that separately.  If you do as you describe then you will not be able to process I/O events while you are waiting on the message queue.

@RuiXinLin, but if you insist on dropping out of the event dispatcher to process messages, then your mechanism for waiting on an empty message queue probably should not be based on libevent.  Perhaps associate a counting semaphore with the message queue. Increment it every time a message is added to the queue, and require that the message processor decrement it (for each message it processes) in order proceed.  That's simple, thread-safe, and fairly natural.
